# Data Structure in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

We have the following assignment:

> Write a program that takes from standard input an expression without
>   left parentheses and prints the equivalent infix expression with the
>   parentheses inserted. For example, given the input
>   `1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 ) * 5 - 6 ) ) )`
>     your program should print
>   `( ( 1 + 2 ) * ( ( 3 - 4 ) * ( 5 - 6 ) )`

This is my new code

```
package program;

import java.util.Scanner;

public  class Program {
    private  static String Buffer = "" ;

    public  static  void main (String args []) {
        String pattern = "1 + 2) * 3 - 4) * 5 - 6)))" ;
        pattern = new StringBuilder(pattern).reverse().toString();
        In in = new In (new Scanner (pattern));
        CompleteBracket(in);
        Buffer = new StringBuilder(Buffer).reverse().toString();
        StdOut.println(Buffer);
    }

    private  static  void CompleteBracket (In in) {
        if (in.isEmpty()) 
            return ;
        String p1 = in.readString ();
        Output (p1);
        if (p1.equals (")" ))
            CompleteBracket (in);

        if (in.isEmpty()) 
            return ;
        String op = in.readString() ;
        Output(op);

        if (in.isEmpty()) 
            return ;
        String p2 = in.readString() ;
        Output(p2);
        if (p2.equals(")"))
            CompleteBracket(in);

        Output("(");
    }

    private  static  void Output (String s) {
        //Buffer += String.format ("%s" , s);
        Buffer += s;
    }
}
```

run:
`(5-6)))`
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
It only prints out the last part.

Comment: You got awesome assignment. Good luck.

Comment: No, we won't write for you. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have done this before. Next homework please.

Comment: Is it also ASAP and Urgent?

Comment: @Simz he didn't ask us to tell him what we did, just asked us to do it. ;)

Comment: Yes it's very URGENT needed ASAP have other more important things to do. Please, Thanks

Comment: @MicahLeeChan are you really serious?

Comment: hava a look at the concept of parser and interpreters:)

Comment: @Simz yes i'm serious we have also have web programming and visual basic assingments. Please, i need help just tell me my mistakes i have already put my own code just help me to fix it thanks

Comment: With your edit, your show of effort, the question is a lot better. Now you're asking what the mistakes are. Well - does this code compile? Does it give messages? What happens when you try it?  Add this into the question, along with your own thinking.

Comment: Voted to reopen, but again question may closed with off-topic until and unless you specify what errors you're getting.

Comment: Why should it print `( ( 1 + 2 ) * ( ( 3 - 4 ) * ( 5 - 6 ) )`? The number of `(` and `)` does not match.

Comment: Class In hasn't been posted, so its impossible to tell whether the code as shown is correct. And the definition of the task is ambiguous, there's more than one way to balance the parentheses...

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
import static sun.java2d.cmm.ColorTransform.In;
```

Which is almost certainly not the right class to use.

I am assuming `In` was provided as part of your home work.  If not you don't appear to need it, I would just use the `Scanner` you have already.

Some other points;

- Using camelCase for field and methods, otherwise `String Buffer` could be confused with `StringBuffer`
- don't use StringBuffer, as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.
- Don't put in redundant `;;` and `()` and this makes readability harder.
- "% s" is not the same as "%s" in fact you don't need to format a String as a String as it is a String already. try

  ```
  buffer += s;
  ```

Comment: `sun.java2d.cmm.ColorTransform.In` is not even a class, it's a `int` field in a interface, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/java2d/cmm/ColorTransform.java#ColorTransform.0In

Comment: @fabian well spotted, I just saw `sun.java2d` and suspected the wrong class had been imported. I suspect it should be a variable called `in` not a class.

Answer (score 0):

This should print the expected infix expression:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class InfixExpression {

    static final String LEFT_PARENTHESIS = "(";
    static final String RIGHT_PARENTHESIS = ")";
    static final String SPACE = " ";
    static final String MULTIPLICATION_OPERATION = "*";
    static final String ADDITION_OPERATION = "+";
    static final String SUBTRACTION_OPERATION = "-";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //  1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 ) * 5 - 6 ) ) ) !
        //  55 + 99 ) * 1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 ) * 5 - 6 ) ) ) ) !
        Stack<String> operationsStack = new Stack();
        Stack<String> expressionsStack = new Stack();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!scanner.hasNext("!")) {
            String s = scanner.next();
            if (s.equals(MULTIPLICATION_OPERATION)
                    || s.equals(ADDITION_OPERATION)
                    || s.equals(SUBTRACTION_OPERATION)) {
                operationsStack.push(s);
            } else if (s.equals(RIGHT_PARENTHESIS)) {
                String operandMostRecent = expressionsStack.pop();
                String operandSecondMostRecent = expressionsStack.pop();
                String operation = operationsStack.pop();
                //Build subexpression with left and right parentheses and operation, e.g. ( ( 3 - 4 ) * ( 5 - 6 ) )
                String infixSubExpression = LEFT_PARENTHESIS
                        + SPACE
                        + operandSecondMostRecent
                        + SPACE
                        + operation
                        + SPACE
                        + operandMostRecent
                        + SPACE
                        + s;
                expressionsStack.push(infixSubExpression);
            } else {
                expressionsStack.push(s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(expressionsStack.pop());
    }
}
```